# how to set default onDraw of View for preview in graphical layout mode

Tags: android, custom-view

I made class MyView which is extedning View, the goal is to draw in some way (not important to the problem) points. To contain points, MyView has array of coordinates.  I'v created also some attributes to customization MyView (like size of the point, shape, colour, etc.).

Because of the attributes I want to have preview of MyView in graphical layout. Preview bases on onDraw() method, so if array of points is empty I want to draw nothing (when app is running on emulator or mobile) BUT to have preview I want to draw few points in default position. In both cases array is empty, so how can I check when is onDraw invoke (preview in graphical layout or  running) or set different onDraw methode for preview than for running application?